# pg_fetch_row() does not return result count zero

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

My problem is `pg_fetch_row()` does not return result when I only `echo $queryCountRow[0]` but when I add a string in front/back `eg. echo "count: $queryCountRow[0]"` it returns the result count `eg. count: 0`. Can anybody know how to fix this?

```
$queryCount = "SELECT COUNT(column) FROM table WHERE column1 = 'xxx'";
$queryCountResult = pg_query($db, $queryCount);
$queryCountRow = pg_fetch_row($queryCountResult);

echo $queryCountRow[0];

if ($queryCountRow[0] == 0)
```

EDIT: The result is 0, but when the result is greater than 0 it return the count.

Comment: where is your actual code that you use to echo? Is it possible you are doing something like `if($queryCountRow[0])`, which would return false when it is `0`.

Comment: this is my actual code `echo $queryCountRow[0];`

Comment: Is that right after `$queryCountRow = pg_fetch_row($queryCountResult);` or later in your code?

Comment: have you tried `echo "$queryCountRow[0]";`? If `echo $queryCountRow[0];` does not echo when it is 0, my only thought is that `$queryCountRow[0]` is being cast a boolean, and not as a string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327773/why-wont-php-print-0-value

Comment: Yes I tried that and still no result. If the result is zero then no result at all.

Comment: have you tried `var_dump($queryCountRow);`?

Comment: It returns string(1) "0", how to handle this in if statement?

Comment: have you tried `if($queryCountRow[0] !== '0')`?

Comment: Yes. Still no luck at all.

Comment: @JAlcantara, did you realy do `var_dump($queryCountRow);` or did you do `var_dump($queryCountRow[0]);` because that output is not an array as expected.

Comment: I already tried that, and return a result. My problem is when I echo only `0` it echo an empty.